# Will installing Nvidia CUDA ver10 break CUDA ver9 on the same machine?

Tags: tensorflow, cuda, pytorch, nvidia

I am currently using pytorch and tensorflow with cuda ver9.0. I am pondering whether to install the latest cuda version 10. Will installing cuda v10 break cuda v9? Can both co-exist on the same desktop PC? Is it advisable to uninstall cuda v9 after installing cuda v10 or is it better to leave both versions installed?

I am using Windows 10.

Comment: It doesn't have to.  They can coexist.  The methods to make them coexist vary by windows vs. linux.  The cool thing about CUDA is that if you install the latest GPU driver, any previous versions of CUDA can coexist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question. Installing CUDA v10 will not break CUDA v9 on the same machine. Both can co-exist.

I installed CUDA v10 successfully. Pytorch has been tested to work successfully with CUDA v10.